# Except compares items from calling (first) collection

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, iequalitycomparer

I'm using Enumerable.Except() to exclude **skipSerialNumbers** items from **activatedSerialNumbers**.

```
activatedSerialNumbers = activatedSerialNumbers
                    .Except(skipSerialNumbers, new SamWithLicenseComparer()).ToList();
```

**SamWithLicenseComparer** is:

```
internal class SamWithLicenseComparer : IEqualityComparer<SamWithLicense>
{
    public bool Equals(SamWithLicense x, SamWithLicense y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) 
            return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        if(x.Name.ToLower() != y.Name.ToLower())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SamWithLicense sam)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(sam, null)) 
            return 0;
        return sam.Name == null ? 0 : sam.Name.ToLower().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

As a result I get unexpected value, because, as I found out, items from **activatedSerialNumbers** compare with themselves. But the logic is that they may have the same names, task is just remove all items from **skipSerialNumbers**. How to do that avoiding an extra comparison?

Comment: I think not all code paths return value in your Equals method. Are you missing `return true` at the end?

Comment: If you want to compare ignoring upper and lower case, there are specific methods to do it. For example `string.Compare(x, y, true)` or even better `string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` so that everyone that sees it knows what is happening (and can begin pestering you on why `CurrentCulture`). Then clearly the GetHashCode should use: `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(sam)`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky thank you, I just missed this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Except` is a set operation so the result will contain always distinct values.
For example if you do `{A,B,A,C}.Except({B,C})` you'll get `{A}`, not `{A, A}`.

You can try this:

```
var skipSesialNumbersSet = new HashSet<SamWithLicense>(skipSerialNumbers, new SamWithLicenseComparer());
activatedSerialNumbers = activatedSerialNumbers.Where(x => !skipSesialNumbersSet.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: you need to actually add the items to be removed to the hashset, but other than that, this is right

Comment: Using a HashSet for skipSesialNumbersSet will still result in a distinct of the second collection. For example 1, 1, 3, 4 except 1, 3 will result in 4 and not result in 1, 4. So there is still a distict of 1 being done.

Comment: @AlexSiepman: well `{1,1,3,4}` except `{1,3}` has to be `{4}`... I don't think the OP wants to remove specific sub-sequences, but all the occurrences of certain values...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the duplicates also, you can use this variant of Except:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptWithDuplicates<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
        IEnumerable<TSource> second)
    {
        if (first == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("first"); }
        if (second == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("second"); }

        var secondList = second.ToList();
        return first.Where(s => !secondList.Remove(s));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptWithDuplicates<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
        IEnumerable<TSource> second,
        IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
    {
        if (first == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("first"); }
        if (second == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("second"); }
        var comparerUsed = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;

        var secondList = second.ToList();
        foreach (var item in first)
        {
            if (secondList.Contains(item, comparerUsed))
            {
                secondList.Remove(item);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can do this:

```
var first = new [] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
var second = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 4 };

var withoutDuplicates = first.Except(second);  // 3 
var witDuplicates = first.ExceptWithDuplicates(second);  // 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 : Note that 1 and 2 are also in the list
```